# App not deploying with "start node.js" script

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, discord.js, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a Discord bot with Google Cloud. Whenever I try to deploy using `gcloud app deploy`, I get this error:

```
> discord-bot@1.0.0 start /app
> node index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js-commando'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:1:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-12-09T05_48_58_649Z-debug.log
```

This is what my package.json looks like:

```
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.11"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Error is clearly seen "Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js-commando'". Add "discord.js-commando" in package.json

Answer (score 0):

try install the required package `discord.js-commando`. It's not in package.json. You can install it with `npm install discord.js-commando --save`

Comment: Wow, I was dumb. That worked. Thank you for the help!